# Inconsistency in solutions using CVXPY

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, cvxpy

Please, consider the following optimisation problem. Specifically, `x` and `b` are `(1,n)` vectors, `C` is `(n,n)` symmetric matrix, `k` is an arbitrary constant and `i` is a `(1,n)` vector of ones.

[image]

Please, also consider the following equivalent optimisation problem. In such case, `k` is determined during the optimisation process so there is no need to scale the values in `x` to obtain the solution `y`.

[image]

Please, also consider the following code for solving both the problems with `cvxpy`.

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

def problem_1(C):
    n, t = np.shape(C)
    
    x = cp.Variable(n)
    b = np.array([1 / n] * n)
    
    obj =  cp.quad_form(x, C)
    constraints = [b.T @ cp.log(x)>=0.5, x >= 0]
    cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(obj), constraints).solve()

    return (x.value / (np.ones(n).T @ x.value))

def problem_2(C):
    n, t = np.shape(C)
    
    y = cp.Variable(n)
    k = cp.Variable()
    b = np.array([1 / n] * n)
    
    obj =  cp.quad_form(y, C)
    constraints = [b.T @ cp.log(y)>=k, np.ones(n)@y.T==1, y >= 0]
    cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(obj), constraints).solve()
    
    return y.value
```

While the first function do provide me with the correct solution for a sample set of data I am using, the second does not. Specifically, values in `y` differ heavily while employing the second function with some of them being equal to zero (which cannot be since all values in `b` are positive and greater than zero). I am wondering wether or not the second function minimise also `k`. Its value should not be minimised on the contrary it should just be determined during the optimisation problem as the one that leads to the solution that minimise the objective function.

UPDATE_1

I just found that the solution that I obtain with the second formulation of the problem is equal to the one derived with the following equations and function. It appears that the constraint with the logarithmic barrier and the `k` variable is ignored.

[image]

```
def problem_3(C):
    n, t = np.shape(C)
    
    y = cp.Variable(n)
    k = cp.Variable()
    b = np.array([1 / n] * n)
    
    obj =  cp.quad_form(y, C)
    constraints = [np.ones(n)@y.T==1, y >= 0]
    cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(obj), constraints).solve()
    
    return y.value
```

UPDATE_2

Here is the link to a sample input `C` - https://www.dropbox.com/s/kaa7voufzk5k9qt/matrix_.csv?dl=0. In such case the correct output for both `problem_1` and `problem_2` is approximately equal to `[0.0659 0.068  0.0371 0.1188 0.1647 0.3387 0.1315 0.0311 0.0441]` since they are equivalent by definition. I am able to obtain the the correct output by solving only `problem_1`. Solving `problem_2` leads to `[0.0227 0.     0.     0.3095 0.3392 0.3286 0.     0.     0.    ]` which is wrong since it happens to be the correct output for `problem_3`.

UPDATE_3

To be clear, by definition `problem_2` exhibits solution equal to the solution of `problem_3` when the parameter `k` goes to minus infinity.

UPDATE_4

Please consider the following code that is for solving `problem_1` using SciPy Optimize instead CVXPY. By imposing `k=9` the correct optimal solution can still be achieved which is consistent with `problem_1` being independent of the parameter.

```
import scipy.optimize as opt

def obj(x, C):
    return x.T @ C @ x

def problem_1_1(C):
    n, t = np.shape(C)

    b = np.array([1 / n] * n)
        
    constraints = [{"type": "eq", "fun": lambda x: (b * np.log(x)).sum() - 9}]
    
    res = opt.minimize(
        obj,
        x0 = np.array([1 / n] * n),
        args = (C),
        bounds = ((0, None),) * n, 
        constraints = constraints
    )
    
    return (res['x'] / (np.ones(n).T @ res['x']))
```

UPDATE_5

By considering the code in UPDATE_4, whenever `k` is set equal to 10 the correct solution is still achieved however appears the following warning. I suppose that is due to rounding error that might occur during the optimisation process.

```
Untitled.py:56: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in
log {"type": "eq", "fun": lambda x: (b * np.log(x)).sum() - 10}
```

I am wondering if there is a way to impose strict inequality constraint with CVXPY or apply a condition on the logarithm argument. Please consider the following modified code for `problem_1_1`.

```
import scipy.optimize as opt

def obj(x, C):
    return x.T @ C @ x

def problem_1_1(C):
    n, t = np.shape(C)

    b = np.array([1 / n] * n)
        
    constraints = [{"type": "eq", "fun": lambda x: (b * np.log(x if x.all() > 0 else 1e-100)).sum() - 10}]
    
    res = opt.minimize(
        obj,
        x0 = np.array([1 / n] * n),
        args = (C),
        bounds = ((0, None),) * n, 
        constraints = constraints
    )
    
    return (res['x'] / (np.ones(n).T @ res['x']))
```

UPDATE_6

To be thorough, the correct value of optimal `k` is approximatively `-2.4827186402337564`.

Comment: Equations are hard to read; codecogs?...maybe screen-clip your LaTeX from a well-rendered PDF instead. Also, it would be great if you could provide sample input / output for testing and experimentation, even if synthetic.

Comment: Yes codecogs since there is no LaTex support on stack overflow if I am not mistaken. I have just edited the post including screenshot of the equations and sample input and output.

Comment: Some comments/questions: (1) I can reproduce your results. (2) If I choose larger ks in problem 1 (e.g. k=9), the cvxpy calculation fails, so the problem is not independent of k (and why should it be, it affects the feasible solution space)? (3) So why should it be permitted to make k a variable in problem 2. (4) Clearly, problem 2 and 3 yield the same results: If k is an (unrestricted) variable, then k=-inf is a "reasonable" choice as it will just increase the feasible optimization space. (5) Why do you think (or how did you prove) the two problems are equivalent?

Comment: Thank-you very much for the detailed comments. Most appreciated. (2) Please consider the UPDATE_4. (3) It is considered to be a variable since by definition exists one and only one value of `k` that leads to correct solution that is scaled to one (please consider 1.2 and 1.1). (4) I just checked the value of `k` in `problem_2` after optimising with CVXPY and is equal to `-14.173735793850643` which doesn't look like to be large. (5) the problems have been demonstrated to be equivalent in few academic papers.

Answer (score 0):

If you let [image: formula] be arbitrary then you are basically saying that [image: formula]  is greater or equal to some arbitrary number, which is trivially true, so the constraint becomes irrelevant.

I believe you should either fix the value of [image: formula] or turn this problem into a minimax problem by determining a tadeoff betweenmaximizing [image: formula] and minimizing [image: formula].